# How to have math expression in spoiler block in markdown

Tags: github, math, markdown, mathjax, github-flavored-markdown

I want to have math expression in a spoiler block, actually a `details/summary` block in markdown for a github repository. When I try to use the math synthax using `$$` in the block, the math expression is not displayed properly.

example code:

```
<details> 
  <summary>a)</summary>
$$
    \omega = \sqrt{\frac{4 m g h}{M_{1} R^{2}}}
$$
^ this is not displayed nicely
</details>


$$
    \omega = \sqrt{\frac{4 m g h}{M_{1} R^{2}}}
$$
^ this is displayed nicely
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank line between the HTML and MathJax markers.

```
<details> 
  <summary>a)</summary>
  
$$
    \omega = \sqrt{\frac{4 m g h}{M_{1} R^{2}}}
$$
</details>


$$
    \omega = \sqrt{\frac{4 m g h}{M_{1} R^{2}}}
$$
```

[Demonstration](https://gist.github.com/schwern/1b49a11ced2d092fd8b58ea7d441ec0c)